# How Can We Use Or With Wherebetween Clause in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

---

```
$checking = DB::table('bookings')->whereBetween('checkindate', [$checkindate, $checkoutdate])->first();
```

------My first query--------

```
$checking_2 = DB::table('bookings')->where('checkindate',$checkindate)->where('checkoutdate',$checkoutdate)->first();
```

--------My Second query-------

```
$checking_3 = DB::table('bookings')->whereBetween('checkoutdate',[$checkindate,$checkoutdate])->first();
```

------ My third query-------------

I want to build these queries into a single query but unable to do it can anybody help it with me.
I want to run each query and store the result in a single array .
Main question how to use OR after wherebetween query because if I simply use ->Where it doesn't give me desire result

or can anywrite this code in a single query?

Comment: have you create booking model?

Comment: yes and its related to my user but let me clear sandy this is booking process. i want to check about room is free or not for this date so it can be booked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$checking = DB::table('bookings')
    ->whereBetween('checkindate', [$checkindate, $checkoutdate])
    ->orWhereBetween('checkoutdate',[$checkindate,$checkoutdate])
    ->orWhere(function($query){
        $query->where('checkindate',$checkindate)->where('checkoutdate',$checkoutdate)
    })
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 $camps = DB::table('bookings')->where(function ($q) 
 {
   $q->whereBetween('checkindate', [$checkindate, $checkoutdate])
      ->orWhere(function($q1) {
        $q1->where('checkindate',$checkindate)->where('checkoutdate',$checkoutdate)
      })
     ->orwhereBetween('checkoutdate', [$checkindate, $checkoutdate])
 })->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get the result.

```
->where(function($query) use($checkindate, $checkoutdate) {
    $query->whereBetween('checkindate', [$checkindate, $checkoutdate])
          ->orWhere(function($q) use($checkindate, $checkoutdate) {
            $q->where('checkindate',$checkindate)->where('checkoutdate',$checkoutdate)
          })
          ->orWhereBetween('checkoutdate',[$checkindate,$checkoutdate])
})->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
$checking_2 = DB::table('bookings')->where('checkindate','>=' ,$checkindate)->where('checkoutdate','<=',$checkoutdate)->get();
```

Comment: Sandy thanks for your efforts but this is not working my friend. case in which its working  like room is booked for 12-16 and if i try it with other dates like 11-17 it works but if i try to check it with dates 11-13 . its not working my friend